# Power supply unit with two fans

Tags: power-supply

I have a power supply unit with two fans, but it makes much noise. I know that there are models with one fans.

Would it be harmful if I removed one fan of them?

Comment: ask the manufacturer, they'll probably say yes.. but maybe if you have a temperature monitor that shows you the temperature in there, then you could get away with using one, if you monitor it.. but also if you're in a hot country it may be more of an issue

Comment: The power supply has two fans because it was designed to have two fans.  If you remove a fan then the fan will be running in an unsupported configuration.  Without specifics we wouldn't be able to say one way another if you would harm the product by removing a fan or not.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT open up your power supply. People have quite literally died doing so.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it is not a good idea to remove a fan.
Your mileage may vary.
You have been warned.

1. For well designed power supplies, physical airflow and heat dissipation is a serious design issue, and a lot of engineering time is spent on getting it right.  Removing a fan basically changes the design, which is a quick way to achieve failure and/or fire.
2. For cheap power supplies where the "design" is badly copied from another unit, there was probably little to no care taken in heat dissipation.   Your unit may have two fans because the manufacturer discovered that only one fan made it catch fire.   So removing one fan ...
3. Power supplies are full of high voltages, capacitors that can store electricity after the power is unplugged, and many ways to injure yourself.  It's generally not a good idea for beginners to open the power supply and start disabling things as a first project.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Barry on this... making changes to customise hardware is never a good idea.

When you make changes to a power supply you will void any warranty you have on it and also potentially on the rest of the hardware inside the case.

Your power supply will also likely have multiple fans in there for a reason.  A lot of money will ave probably been put into making the Power Supply and researching its airflow dynamics, cooling requirements etc.

If your power supply is a cheaper power supply, it will likely be a copy of a popular model on the market and the manufacturer may have found that adding a second fan was the only way to keep the unit cool enough to work.

Also, you may get seriously hurt while modifying a power supply.  Even an unplugged supply can potentially carry enough stored energy in its capacitors to kill you.

If killing you isn't scary enough - removing a fan from a power supply and leaving it in a running machine while you are out of the house could cause a fire.  You could burn your house down, put other peoples lives at risks in your property and any ajoining properties.. it's not worth it for the sake of spending a few $/£'s on a new supply.

There are plenty of power suppies out there which are cheap and quiet.. it's not worth the risk.